# Why is thoracic breathing dominant in women while abdominal breathing is dominant in men?

Tags: human-biology, respiration

In human males, lateral movement of thorax constitutes 25% of breathing while abdominal movement accounts for 75% of breathing. It is exactly the opposite in the case of women.

I got this piece of information Trueman's Elementary Biology.

Comment: Welcome to the Biology community. Please improve your question by: 1. Citing sources for the information you provided (i.e. differences in respiratory movements in the sexes), and 2. Describing what efforts you made to answer this question (e.g. reading books or journals, doing your own experiments). This will invite good answers to your question. Cheers!

Comment: Some workers (https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/87456 and https://journals.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/jappl.1975.39.4.608) have observed that respiratory movements do not differ in males and females, at least in quiet breathing. That makes it even more important to cite your sources in this question.

Comment: I think that your question will be correct if you give a reference for the percentages. it is true though, otherwise just take the percentages away and cite this paper: http://rc.rcjournal.com/content/57/9/1442.short ... Upper thoracic movement was significantly decreased with age. There was less abdominal movement in females than in males, except during quiet breathing in the supine position.

Comment: @Meercat Here is a good article that should answer your question: https://breathe.ersjournals.com/content/14/2/131. (You can read and download it for free.)

Comment: Probably an evolutionary feature to prevent pregnancy from making breathing difficult.